# Spamming logs for "Monitor thread successfully connected to server" from MongoDB java driver

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, mongodb-java

I was given a Spring application to work on and upon running it on my local, I noticed a continuous spamming (every 10s) of below on console

> Monitor thread successfully connected to server with description ServerDescription {address=some_replica_member_name.mongodb.net:27017, type=REPLICA_SET_PRIMARY, state=CONNECTED..

I am aware that it is used to poll the server to check its status but in all the other applications I've worked with, I've never seen such log being spammed unless there is actual connection going on. What gives? Setup is just

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb+srv://user:xxx@some.mongo.host.net/some_db
```

Comment: Reduce driver's log level?